# refrence a variable inside a instances

Tags: php

This is our class that is called

```
 <?php

class Nest
{
    public $debug;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $cookieFile;

    public function __construct($username, $password, $debug = false)
    {
        // Set the properties
        $this->debug     = $debug;
        $this->username  = $username;
        $this->password  = $password;
        $this->useragent = 'Nest/1.1.0.10 CFNetwork/548.0.4';
        $this->cookieFile = tempnam('/tmp', 'nest-cookie');

        // Login
        $response = $this->curlPost('https://home.nest.com/user/login', 'username=' . urlencode($username) . '&password=' . urlencode($password));

        if (($json = json_decode($response)) === false)
            throw new Exception('Unable to connect to Nest');

        // Stash information needed to make subsequence requests
        $this->access_token = $json->access_token;
        $this->user_id = $json->userid;
        $this->transport_url = $json->urls->transport_url;
    }

    public function house_state_set($state)
    {
        switch ($state)
        {
            case 'away':
                $away = true;
                break;
            case 'home':
                $away = false;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception('Invalid state given: "' . $state . '"');
        }

        $status = $this->status_get();

        $structure_id = $status->user->{$this->user_id}->structures[0];
        $payload = json_encode(array('away_timestamp' => time(), 'away' => $away, 'away_setter' => 0));
        return $this->curlPost($this->transport_url . '/v2/put/' . $structure_id, $payload);
    }

    public function house_state_get()
    {
        $status = $this->status_get();

        $structure = $status->user->{$this->user_id}->structures[0];
        list (,$structure_id) = explode('.', $structure);
        return ($status->structure->{$structure_id}->away ? 'away' : 'home');
    }


    public function temperature_set(&$temp)
    {
        $status = $this->status_get();

        $structure = $status->user->{$this->user_id}->structures[0];
        list (,$structure_id) = explode('.', $structure);
        $device = $status->structure->{$structure_id}->devices[0];
        list (,$device_serial) = explode('.', $device);
        $temperature_scale = $status->device->{$device_serial}->temperature_scale;

        if ($temperature_scale == "F")
        {
            $target_temp_celsius = (($temp - 32) / 1.8);
        }
        else
        {
            $target_temp_celsius = $temp;
        }

        $payload = json_encode(array('target_change_pending' => true, 'target_temperature' => $target_temp_celsius));
        return $this->curlPost($this->transport_url . '/v2/put/shared.' . $device_serial, $payload);
    }

    public function status_get()
    {
        $response = $this->curlGet($this->transport_url . '/v2/mobile/user.' . $this->user_id);

        if (($json = json_decode($response)) === false)
            throw new Exception('Unable to gather the status from Nest');

        return $json;
    }

    private function curlGet($url, $referer = null, $headers = null)
    {

        $headers[] = 'Authorization: Basic ' . $this->access_token;
        $headers[] = 'X-nl-user-id:' . $this->user_id;
        $headers[] = 'X-nl-protocol-version: 1';

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookieFile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookieFile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->useragent);
        if(!is_null($referer)) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
        if(!is_null($headers)) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

        $html = curl_exec($ch);

        if(curl_errno($ch) != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error during GET of '$url': " . curl_error($ch));
        }

        $this->lastURL = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
        $this->lastStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        return $html;
    }

    private function curlPost($url, $post_vars = '', $referer = null)
    {
        if (isset($this->access_token)) $headers[] = 'Authorization: Basic ' . $this->access_token;
        if (isset($this->user_id)) $headers[] = 'X-nl-user-id:' . $this->user_id;
        $headers[] = 'X-nl-protocol-version: 1';

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookieFile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookieFile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->useragent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_vars);
        if(!is_null($headers)) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

        $html = curl_exec($ch);

        $this->lastURL = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
        $this->lastStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        return $html;
    }
}
```

and is called with:

```
<?php
$new = $_GET['t'];
include_once('nest.php');
$nest = new Nest('usr', 'pwd');
$nest->temperature_set($new);
?>
```

If I replace $new with a number and then call the function it works but not in it current form. I have tried using the class to call outside variables, tried to just call but cant figure where and why its not working.

Comment: Should work. Are you sure you use `$nest->temperature_set($new);` and `$new` has the correct value which you want?!

Comment: I was thinking the same but our script is <?php
$new = $_GET['t'];
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// include the nest api library
include_once('nest.php');
// create new nest object w/ login information
$nest = new Nest(xxxxxxxx);
// set the temp to 9 degrees
$nest->temperature_set($new);
?>

Comment: You need to give us a [mcve] so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I have updated our question to help give a clearer example

Comment: Are you sure it works when you pass a value and it doesn't when you pass a variable?!

Comment: I just retired put a number in place of the variable even set the variable to a number and only the first works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108221/discussion-between-jjohn-and-rizier123).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is not working because your device is configured to use Celsius.

PHP is a dynamically typed language, as is JavaScript, but sometimes people forget that both will change types based on context (and sometimes the type conversion will have unexpected results).

All $_REQUEST variables are strings. Try changing:

```
$target_temp_celsius = $temp;
```

To

```
$target_temp_celsius = $temp + 0;
```

(JSON is strongly typed)